# Studying representations of orthogonal group via symmetric group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices with real entries. On $V$ we have the natural action of the orthogonal group $\textrm{O}(n)$ defined by $g.A:=g\cdot A\cdot g^{t}$ for $g\in\textrm{O}(n)$ and $A\in V$. We identify $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the set of diagonal matrices. Thus we get an inclusion $\textrm{diag}:\mathbb{R}^n\hookrightarrow V$. Now let $G=\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements. Considering $G$ as the subgroup of $\textrm{O}(n)$ consisting of permutation matrices, we get an action of $G$ both on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V$ that makes $\textrm{diag}$ to a homomorphism of $G$-modules. If we pass to the dual map, we get a surjective homomorphism of $G$-modules $$\textrm{diag}^\vee:V\to\mathbb{R}^n.$$ The decomposition of the $\textrm{O}(n)$-module $V$ into irreducibles is $(\mathbb{R}\cdot\textrm{I}_n)\oplus V_0$ where $\textrm{I}_n$ is the identity matrix and $V_0$ is the set of traceless matrices. We note that the image under $\textrm{diag}^\vee$ of both is an irreducible $G$-module. My question is, whether this property is preserved under taking the symmetric power:

Let $W$ be an irreducible $\textrm{O}(n)$-submodule of $\textrm{Sym}^p(V)$. Is it true that $\textrm{diag}^\vee(W)$ is irreducible as $G$-module?